# Block validation files?

Tags: blockchain, development, block, validation

Which part of the code is responsible for validating blocks? I'm working on a BIP to modify the structure of block.h, and I think that would definitely affect the validation process. Can anyone point me in the right direction for the files I would need to change to update the validation process?

Answer (score 1):

Conveniently, the file is called [validation.cpp](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/validation.cpp).  You probably want to look at the function `CheckBlock`.